# Exception while reading data from keyboard

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm newbie in Java and I'm trying to read data from keyboard but I'm getting an exception and I don't know why and how to fix it.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test r = new Test();
        
        System.out.println("Type a int number      : " + r.readInteger());
        System.out.println("type a double number: " + r.readDouble());
    }

    public int readInteger() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int val = 0;
        
        while(true) {
            if(input.hasNextInt()) {
                val = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid data type.");
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }

        input.close();

        return val;
    }

    double readDouble() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double val = 0;
        
        while(true) {
            if(input.hasNextDouble()) {
                val = input.nextDouble();
                input.nextLine();
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid data type.");
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }

        input.close();

        return val;
    }
}
```

The excpetion:

> [roger@archroger ~]$ java Test
>
> 3
>
> Type a int number      : 3
>
> Invalid data type.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>
> at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
>
> at Test.readDouble(Test.java:44)
>
> at Test.main(Test.java:8)

Answer (score 1):

Don't close the scanner when it's input stream is `System.in`. This will close the standard input as well and statements like `scanner.nextLine()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` when you do not check if the line is present. You check with `scanner.hasNextInt()` if another integer token is available and then try to get another line with `scanner.getNextLine()` without testing if this line exists at all. Use `scanner.hasNextLine()`.